# phpunit - Selenium Code Coverage

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, code-coverage

I have written a simple Selenium Test case for PHP and would like to get the code coverage.

I have followed the following steps to set up code coverage for my sut which currently resides locally on a mamp server however coverage keeps showing up as 0.

1. Placed phpunit_coverage.php in root directory of web server.
2. Placed append and prepend files to their respective paths in php.ini
3. Upadated my test class with the following :

   protected $coverageScriptUrl = 'http://localhost/phpunit_coverage.php';

The tests are generating the coverage-data files within the root directory of the web server as expected (I can see these files being generated while tests are running), however it seems that these files are not being parsed by the phpunit_coverage and the clover / html file data keeps showing 0 code coverage, which should not be the case.